# How to extract parameters from a non-stationary generalized Pareto (GP) model in R?

Tags: r, parameters, distribution

I am now using the `extRemes` package to build a non-stationary GP model, and I find it difficult to extract the parameters.

## Non-stationary scale parameter

```
library(extRemes)
data(Fort)
fit1 <- fevd(Prec, Fort, threshold=0.395,
        scale.fun=~sin(2 * pi * (year - 1900)/365.25) + cos(2 * pi * (year - 1900)/365.25),
        type="GP", use.phi=TRUE, verbose=TRUE)
```

[image]

According to the `fevd` help page, `log(scale(y)) = phi(y) = phi0 + phi1 * g1(y) + phi2 * g2(y) + ...`

Now, we have `phi0`, `phi1`, and `phi2` from the results, but what are `g1(y)` and `g2(y)` in the above function?

Also, how can we understand the `scale.fun` in `fit1`? What does `scale.fun=~sin(2 * pi * (year - 1900)/365.25) + cos(2 * pi * (year - 1900)/365.25)` stand for? For example, if we use `scale.fun=~Fort$year`, we assume that `year` has a linear influence on the `scale` parameter.

## Non-stationary threshold

```
fit2 <- fevd(Prec, Fort, threshold=0.475, threshold.fun=~I(-0.15 * cos(2 * pi * month / 12)),
        type="GP", verbose=TRUE)
```

[image]

From `fit2`, how can we compute the changing `threshold` values based on `threshold.fun = ~I(-0.15 * cos(2 * pi * month/12))`? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The g1(y) etc. are the functions you gave to fevd via the scale.fun argument.  So, phi0 is like an intercept term, ph1 is the coefficient for sin(2 * pi * (year - 1900)/365.25), etc.  Because you used use.phi = TRUE, your model for the scale parameter is estimated to be: log( scale ) = -0.84 - 0.23 * sin(2 * pi * (year - 1900)/365.25) - 0.25 * cos(2 * pi * (year - 1900)/365.25), and your estimated shape parameter is about 0.21 (so heavy-tailed).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't see that there was a second question.  I would recommend giving the threshold argument a vector of differing thresholds instead of using the threshold.fun argument.  I'm not 100% certain of what that argument really does.  It was supposed to be the same as passing in a vector, and while it seems to do something reasonably close, I can't explain it very well because I don't understand it.  But, it was supposed to be, in your example, u(month) = I(-0.15 * cos(2 * pi * month/12)).

Comment: Can you please edit your original answer to include this additional material as well?

Comment: I think you gave the answer somewhere else:) Following https://ral.ucar.edu/~ericg/extRemes/extRemes2.pdf p. 35 we should give a formula in `threshold.fun` and the corresponding coefficients in `threshold`. This is consistent with a single value in `threshold` along with the default formula. I think that this mechanism would work well with a `predict` method because we can recompute the threshold on some  `newdata`, and use e.g., a threshold computed by a quantile regression.